# Redirect users to web page after wifi connect

Tags: redirect, raspberry-pi, wifi, captiveportal

For service purposes I want to connect via wifi to a raspberry pi as ap. Afterwards a local website should be called automatically.

The AP mode works and the client gets an ip assigned. In the local DNS I have set that all requests point to the local ip and the local apache answers with a 302 to the url of the service page.

If I connect with a smartphone, it gets an ip, but does not open the website, but only notices that there is no internet connection (and that's ok).

How do I get the client to open my page?

Thanks in advance
craCH